# Can a WCF client using HTTP call a WCF service returning HTTPS, or can the service redirect to an HTTPS svc?

Tags: wcf, https, wcf-binding

I've been tasked to receive a WCF client call over HTTP and to return the values from the WCF service over HTTPS.  At first, I was using a global.asax to take calls to the HTTP service address and then redirect them to the HTTPS service address.  However, the the WCF client threw an error.

Is it possible to have a WCF client make a call to a WCF service over HTTP, and then have that WCF service return a message over HTTPS?  Thank-you very much for any ideas & help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not using some sort of duplexing mechanism, then no, this isn't possible. The client initiates the http/https connection over tcp and the data is returned over the same connection instance.

Answer (score 0):

The way a connection is setup does not allow the transport protocol to be changed between the request and the associated answer. At least, this goes for the regular http or https connection (WCF Per call).

However, when you try to setup a duplex channel, it might be possible to achieve this. For duplex communication the client effectively publishes an endpoint that the server can call-back to to post the answer over a new connection. This might give the opportunity to have the client publish an https endpoint while the server publishes a http endpoint.

Please visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx for details on how to setup a Duplex WCF communication channel.